# Cannot pass SHA1WithRSA certificates to browser using SslStream

Tags: c#, ssl, https, bouncycastle

I'm currently building a C# Intermediate Proxy server that supports HTTPS, and I'm rebundling certificates in a somewhat nasty way, but it's what I need for this project.

I'm using BouncyCastle to generate a CA certificate and a HTTP-suitable certificate, and I've noticed that `SslStream` will not accept any certificate Signature Algorithms that are not `MD5WithRSA`, and this means that Google Chrome and Firefox will simply refuse to open pages, because it expects `SHA1WithRSA` for it's signature algorithm.

The full code block I'm using to generate and authenticate to the SSL stream is at http://cdn.afterlifelochie.rocket-it.com.au/temp/proxy-https.c-sharp.txt, but here's the short snippet that returns an error.

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(
    cert, false, SslProtocols.Default | SslProtocols.Tls | 
        SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2,  false);
```

Where `cert` is the signed HTTPS certificate with the CA inside the chain, including the CA Private Key and the HTTPS Private Key, returns this error:

```
SSL-Exception: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken messag
e, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToke
n message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, A
syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 coun
t, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes
, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocol
Request asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToke
n message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, A
syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 coun
t, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes
, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocol
Request asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToke
n message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, A
syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 coun
t, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes
, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocol
Request asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToke
n message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, A
syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 coun
t, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes
, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocol
Request asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byt
e[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyRes
ult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(X509Certificate serverC
ertificate, Boolean clientCertificateRequired, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols,
 Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at HTTPProxyServer.ProxyServer.DoHttpProcessing(TcpClient client) in C:\Users
\AfterLifeLochie\Desktop\C#Proxy\ProxyServer.cs:line 324

SSL-Inner-Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted
```

However, if I change line 76's parameter `SetSignatureAlgorithm(String Method)` to `MD5withRSA` from `SHA1WithRSA`, everything works fine, all the data is transferred properly (except for Google Chrome's over-secure paranoid "you can't continue" message).

Is this a problem with the `SslStream`, the certificate chain, the way I'm authenticating, or something else I've overlooked?

**Update 1:** I grabbed a certificate and CA certificate from my Windows 2008R2 Active Directory Certificate Server instance. Apparently using that certificate works fine, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm assuming it's either to do with chaining the certificates together, the physical generation, or that I'm missing one of the important Subject, Usages, or Extended/Enhanced Usages.

**Update 2:** I realized the CA certificate was changing each time the software generated a new key; this has since been changed and locked, and I can see that the thumbprint and data doesn't change. Still getting `SSL-Inner-Exception: The specified data could not be decrypted` though.

Comment: FWIW, Fiddler's pluggable certificate maker uses the BouncyCastle libraries to generate SHA-1 hashed certificates and these work fine with all browsers. Unfortunately, your original source file is down, so I can't see where the problem may lie. If you're using the DotNetUtilities class, be sure to pull the latest from their CVS, since v1.7.0 had a padding bug for certain private keys. (Note: If you use FiddlerCore, I'll handle this stuff for you :-)

Comment: Hi...did you find the solution? I am also trying to develop the application that is being developed by you. I too have exactly the same problem. I believe that when we ask for response, we can get certificate from respective website. And the same should be passed to the client. How did you solve the issue? Please help. I am in deadly need.  Check the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498447/web-proxy-server-application-for-https-requests

Comment: No, no solution has yet been found. I haven't done much more digging since this was posted, and I'm fairly certain it's still something SSPI related. Good luck!